How can I improve my R code for a two-way repeated measures ANOVA to produce the correct degrees of freedom?
I am running a two-way repeated measures ANOVA in rstudio and I find that the output of the analysis produces some strange degrees of freedom and I worry that the analysis is not accurate as a result. My residuals are 352 when I think they should be less than 30 and despite having 12 timepoints, my df for the "Point" part of the output is just 1.
Context: I am trying to compare intoxication scores, over 12 timepoints, for 3 conditions. My dataset has 30 subjects in it and each subject has 12 entries corresponding to the 12 timepoints. I believe the issue is caused by R interpreting the 360 rows as individual groups, and also not recognizing that there are 12 levels of the "Point" factor.
My output for the RM ANOVA looks like this:
Error: Within
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Point             1   15.4  15.444  14.774 0.000144 ***
Condition         2   36.8  18.410  17.611 5.13e-08 ***
Point:Condition   2    0.4   0.176   0.169 0.844842    
Residuals       352  368.0   1.045

A snippet of my dataset
ID Condition Day Intox_score Point
2341    T   1   0   1
2341    T   1   1   2
2341    T   1   0   3
2341    T   2   3   4
2341    T   2   2   5
2341    T   2   3   6
2341    T   3   0   7
2341    T   3   2   8
2341    T   3   3   9
2341    T   4   2   10
2341    T   4   1   11
2341    T   4   1   12

I'd like to add that I am a very inexperienced user, and have done all analyses possible using base R up to this point. If it's possible to address the issue still using base R that would be preferable. I have limited time to rectify the issue and I worry about learning to use another package and redoing my analyses. It may also be possible that I am misunderstanding the statistical component of the degrees of freedom here, but I thought I'd be able to produce a reliable result either way.
I tried to use the aov() function, which is base R I believe, and my code looks like this:
behint_rm_anova <- aov(Intox_score ~ Point * Condition + Error(ID/Point), data = Behavioral_intox_data_v4_for_R)

summary(behint_rm_anova)

I expected my degrees of freedom for "Point" to be my levels of the factor (12) minus 1 = 11
Instead my output just shows 1 for the degrees of freedom.
I also expected my residuals to be 27 (30 subjects - 3 groups) but my output shows 352.
I tried changing my error term in my code to: "Error(ID/DAY)" and I tried removing it all together thinking maybe this would change how R interprets these things, but this did not change my degrees of freedom.
Thank you so kindly for your feedback/help, it is greatly appreciated.

I suspect you did not code your Point (and possibly ID) column as a factor().
Example Data Like Yours
set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:30, each = 12),
  Condition = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 120),
  Point = rep(1:12, 30)
)

data$Intox_score[data$Condition == "A"] <- 1 + 0.09 * data$Point[data$Condition == "A"] + rnorm(120)
data$Intox_score[data$Condition == "B"] <- 2 + 0.09 * data$Point[data$Condition == "B"] + rnorm(120)
data$Intox_score[data$Condition == "C"] <- 3 + 0.09 * data$Point[data$Condition == "C"] + rnorm(120)

Plot
with(
  data, 
  interaction.plot(
    Point, Condition, Intox_score
  )
)


ID and Point as Numeric
m_1 <- aov(Intox_score ~ Point * Condition + Error(ID/Point), data)
summary(m_1)
#> 
#> Error: ID
#>           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
#> Condition  1  204.1   204.1
#> 
#> Error: ID:Point
#>       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
#> Point  1   29.4    29.4
#> 
#> Error: Within
#>                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> Point             1   14.0  13.964  14.998 0.000128 ***
#> Condition         2   27.6  13.788  14.809 6.68e-07 ***
#> Point:Condition   2    0.1   0.070   0.075 0.927833    
#> Residuals       352  327.7   0.931                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

ID and Point as Factors
data$ID <- factor(data$ID)
data$Point <- factor(data$Point)

m_2 <- aov(Intox_score ~ Point * Condition + Error(ID/Point), data)
summary(m_2)
#> 
#> Error: ID
#>           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> Condition  2 231.70  115.85   116.9 5.04e-14 ***
#> Residuals 27  26.75    0.99                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Error: ID:Point
#>                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> Point            11  48.32   4.393   4.799 8.31e-07 ***
#> Point:Condition  22  24.37   1.108   1.210    0.237    
#> Residuals       297 271.83   0.915                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0
